# Decrease text alpha effect swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to smoothly decrease label transparency horizontally. It should look something like that (im sorry for quality):

[image]

I did try:
 - add horizontal gradient on right side of label container view
 - add view with same background color above and set it alpha to 0.25, 0.5 ..

None of above work.

Comment: When reviewing the answers in the duplicate, simply change the colors such that one has an alpha of 1 and the other has an alpha of 0.

Comment: @rmaddy i still can't change UILabel color and alpha with that..

Comment: Unless you post a question clearly showing what you are trying, no one can help.

Comment: @rmaddy i did post an image that contain text. Text color should change it transparency from 1.0 to 0.5